# ParseUser Module: Only create user if email is verified

Tags: android, email, parse-platform

I am using ParseUser for user Management module.

While the users can be created and email verification can be sent successfully, I would like to further only allow users with email verified to be created, else the email verification process is meaningless.

### Code:

```
            ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
            user.setUsername(ed_username.getText().toString());
            user.setPassword(ed_password.getText().toString());
            user.setEmail(ed_email.getText().toString());

            user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() 
            {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) 
                {
                    if (e == null) 
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, First4.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
                        // to figure out what went wrong
                        switch(e.getCode()){
                        case ParseException.USERNAME_TAKEN:
                            tv_error.setText("USERNAME_TAKEN");
                            break;
                        case ParseException.USERNAME_MISSING:
                            tv_error.setText("USERNAME_MISSING");
                            break;
                        case ParseException.PASSWORD_MISSING:
                            tv_error.setText("PASSWORD_MISSING");
                            break;
                        case ParseException.EMAIL_TAKEN:
                            tv_error.setText("EMAIL_TAKEN");
                            break;      
                        case ParseException.INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS:
                            tv_error.setText("INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS");
                            break;                              
                        default:
                            tv_error.setText(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                        sign_up.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
            });
```

### Question:

I would like to ask whether an email could be sent first and only when the user has verified the email link then the user is created afterwards? I cannot think of the correct logic flow.

The email at the same time use for avoiding people spamming of creating user accounts. Then if not using filling unique email as checkpoint, would there be anyway to reduce spamming?

Could anyone please advise? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can sign up the user and send a verification email to his email. but before he verifies the email, don't allow him continue to enter the app.

the user will still be created on Parse even if his email is not verified, but you can run a cloud background job to delete users that exist for say, 1 day but still not has its email verified.